# no type named 'type' in class std::result_of

Tags: c++, asynchronous, future, stdbind

The following code just wouldn't compile:

```
template< typename Fn >  
bool templateFunctionOne( Fn&& fn )
{
   int v = 5;
   return fn( v );
}

template < typename Fn >
bool templateFunctionTwo( Fn&& fn )
{
   std::future< bool > tk( std::async( std::launch::async,
                           &templateFunctionOne< Fn >,
                           std::forward<Fn>(fn ) ) );
   return tk.get();
 }

 bool printThis( int value )
 {
   cout << value << endl;
   return true;
 }

 int main()
 {
    auto func = std::bind( &printThis, std::placeholders::_1 );
    return templateFunctionTwo( func );  
 }
```

when compiling it gives the following error:

> functional::1665:61: error: no type named 'type' in 'class
>   std::result_of< bool  ((std::_Bind(std::_Placeholder<1>))(int)>))(std::_Bind))(int)>&)>'

I simplified the above, still it won't compile with the same error message:

```
template< typename Fn >  
bool templateFunctionOne( Fn&& fn )
{
   return fn();
}

template < typename Fn >
bool templateFunctionTwo( Fn&& fn )
{
   std::future< bool > tk( std::async( std::launch::async,
                           &templateFunctionOne< Fn >,
                           std::forward<Fn>(fn ) ) );
   return tk.get();
 }

 bool printThis()
 {
   return true;
 }

 int main()
 {
    auto func = std::bind( &printThis );
    return templateFunctionTwo( func );  
 }
```

Since now the function `printThis` doesn't require passing in any parameters, binding the call isn't necessary. And when changing the call in the main as follows, it compiles fine:

```
 int main()
 {
    return templateFunctionTwo( &printThis );  
 }
```

Could someone help to explain? I've seen the same kind of errors when passing a function pointer without using `std::ref` to wrap a parameter when its reference is required, but this seems to be something else (or not), what am I missing here?

Comment: Just for your information: the book "Effective C++" suggests in item 34 "Prefer lambdas to std::bind".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
auto func = std::bind( &printThis );
return templateFunctionTwo( func );
```

`func` is Lvalue, so when Lvalue is passed into `templateFunctionTwo` , `Fn` is deduced to be `Fn&` (due to forwarding reference).

Below line

```
&templateFunctionOne< Fn >,
```

means

```
&templateFunctionOne< Fn& >,
```

it implies that `templateFunctionOne` takes its argument by reference,
if you want to pass argument by reference when calling `async`
you need to use wrapper `std::ref` or `std::cref`:

```
   std::future< bool > tk =  std::async( 
               templateFunctionOne< Fn >,
               std::ref( std::forward<Fn>(fn) ) ); // <--- ref added
```

Now your code compiles.

Another way is to use `remove_reference_t<Fn>` or 
`typename std::remove_reference<Fn>::type`
 to remove Lvalue reference from `Fn`:

```
  std::future< bool > tk =  std::async( 
     templateFunctionOne< std::remove_reference_t<Fn> >, // <--- remove_reference_t added 
     std::forward<Fn>(fn)  );
     return tk.get();
```

then `fn` object is passed by value. This version is better than first, because the call

```
 templateFunctionTwo( std::bind( &printThis, std::placeholders::_1 ) )
```

fails when `ref` is used, because `ref` needs to take only Lvalues.

Comment: Thank you so much! I learned something else today. Appreciate your help very much!

Comment: I tried with std::ref to wrap the forwarding function, and it worked great. But when I tried your second approach with std::remove_reference_t<Fn>, and typename std::remove_reference<Fn>::type, neither worked, and I'm getting this error: no matching function for call to 'async( std::launch, <unresolved overloaded function type>, std::_Bind<bool (*())()>&)'   std::forward<Fn>(fn) ).

Comment: @mark What compiler are you using ? If g++, `remove_reference_t` needs c++14. Are you sure that the call is `std::async(templateFunctionOne< typename std::remove_reference<Fn>::type >,std::forward<Fn>(fn));` ?

Comment: Yes sir, I am using g++ with c++14, and I've tried both calls, none seemed to compile

Comment: Interesting thing, I have tested this code with https://godbolt.org/ , code compiles fine when g++ is 6.1 or newer. All g++ versions under 6.1 reject code. MSVC 15/17 compiles fine this code. Maybe there is some bug in g++ under 6 version.

Comment: Make sense, I just checked I've gcc 4.9.3 :-(

Comment: I'm using gcc 4.9.3.  I guess I will need to do some upgrade to a newer version of gcc. Thank you so much rafix07! Even though this hasn't compiled yet I really have learned something from you today. Appreciate it very much!!

Comment: just a quick update, gcc 7.3.0 has been installed, so the code now complies! But when I wrap these two template functions into a struct, I got some other errors now. If you have some time please take a look my new post: 'template augment deduction/substitution failed'. Thank you!

Comment: @mark `this` was in wrong place while binding. I answered to your new question, you can look there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to bind to anything.

```
 #include<thread>
 #include<functional>
 #include<utility>
 #include<future>
 #include<memory>
 #include<iostream>

 template< typename Fn >  
 bool templateFunctionOne( Fn&& fn )
 {
   int v = 5;
   return fn( v );
 }

 template < typename Fn >
 bool templateFunctionTwo( Fn&& fn )
 {
    std::future< bool > tk( std::async( std::launch::async,
                            &templateFunctionOne< Fn >,
                            std::forward<Fn>(fn ) ));
    return tk.get();
  }

  bool printThis( int value )
  {
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
    return true;
  }

  int main()
  {
     //auto func = std::bind( &printThis, std::placeholders::_1 );
     return templateFunctionTwo( &printThis );  
  }
```

Compiles, and when executed returns the expected value of 5.

Comment: Thanks Johnathan, but my problem was when I do want to pass a parameter in the function:-)

Comment: @mark this code is passing a parameter to the print function, from within templateFunction0ne, just like your origional code. I copied it and made the changes I noted and compiled and executed it and it worked fine, as I expected.

Comment: @mark moreover if you do remove the ref qualification in the async call in your example you still can't call it because your placeholder isn't being used. It still won't compile.

Comment: Hi Johnathan, this might have something to do with the compiler I'm using. I am using gcc 4.9.3

Comment: @mark odly enough I'm using C4Droid with what ever the latest GCC plugin is for it. I know it supports the c++17 language but the library that ships with it does not. So I'm essentially stuck with c++14 or c++11 just like you. If you wasn't using at least c++11 your perfect forwarding functions wouldn't compile as type&& did not exist until the c++11 standard.